# Python CronTab IOError

Tags: python, linux, cron

I am using the [python-crontab module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab) to make sure my script is ran every day at 2 pm.

But I am getting some IOErrors when executing the script

```
Traceback:
File "backup.py", line 87, in <module>
system_cron = Crontab()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/crontab.py", line 175, in __init__
self.read(tabfile)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/crontab.py", line 204, in read
raise IOError("Read crontab %s: %s" % (self.user, err))
IOERROR: Read crontab None: no crontab for root
```

crontab -l gives gives me my empty crontab...

*Is this a bug in the module?*

*Do you guys have an alternative module?*

Thanks

Comment: Are you executing this file locally or in your web server?. Could be that you're not executing the script with the right privileges. Are you executing the script as root?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same bug and i solved it by creating manually a cron(whatever) for the user root.

~# ***crontab -e***

copy paste the following line:
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/touch /root/demo90
save it and check by doing ***ls***

After you go back to crontab file "crontab -e" and remove the line added
 You can now execute your script.

hope it help!!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug which has been fixed for the next version:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-crontab/+bug/1258926 -> Targeted for v1.7